# Intermittent Laravel middleware CSRF mismatch error

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, csrf-protection

My app is throwing a `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php` error on some ajax `POST` routes. It's extremely intermittent and it's been going on for some time. There's no pattern I could discern.

Today I got two `POST` requests back-to-back, only one of which threw the error. I compared the request headers and found that:

- Cookie is the same on both requests, something like:

  `XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlF...; kbR_session=eyJpdiI6IjQxZDF...`
- X-XSRF-TOKEN is also the same:

  `eyJpdiI6IlF2RFVVYkpm...`

I'm using Angular (v1.2.12) which as the [Laravel 5.2 documentation states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection) is setting the cookie value automatically.

So if the request headers match, how is it that one request succeeds and the other fails? What am I not looking at?

Comment: Make sure you're not accidentally flushing/regenerating the session.

Comment: @apokryfos would the flushing/regenerating not be apparent in the cookie/header data?

Comment: Probably yes. However if the token is changing on the subsequent request then something may have happened between the time of loading the session and the time of checking the token.

Comment: @apokryfos I don't see the token changing.. that's what I can't figure out. How else can I troubleshoot Laravel's CRSF middleware?